# Scrape table from specific site fastly

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a table from a web the page has total two tables and I am able to scrape it using selenium and pandas. Selenium is used to give the page source to pandas but this is a slow method as I have to scrape almost 15000 same tables in 2 days. The code I use is as below

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = "https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/#results-dog/race_id=1807732&dog_id=539402&r_date=2021-01-01&track_id=4&r_time=13:24"
def extract(url):
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
    wd.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'})
    wd.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    wd.get(url)
    time.sleep(8)

    all_tables = pd.read_html(wd.page_source, attrs={'id': 'sortableTable'})
    all_tables = pd.concat(all_tables)
    all_tables.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I have tried scrapy to read page but *response.css('table')* shows empty list

I have also tried pandas simply with request that also shows no table found.
pandas method

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/#results-dog/race_id=1807732&dog_id=539402&r_date=2021-01-01&track_id=4&r_time=13:24"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')#tried with and without this line

dfs = pd.read_html(page.text)
print(dfs)
```

It would be great help if someone shares alternative fast method
or make amendments in the provided ones to make them fast

Comment: I suggest using Request package to crawl the data of this site. This can speed up. You can see the table data in this link:
https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?race_id=1807732&dog_id=539402&r_date=2021-01-01&track_id=4&r_time=13%3A24&blocks=results-dog-header%2Cresults-dog-details

Comment: I know about this link but dont know how to extract from it

Comment: you should inspect the requests sent when you are visiting the website through chrome devtool, and find the relevant request

Comment: that is the one @SaeedEmamYari gave url for I dont know how to extract from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using Request package to crawl the data of this site. This can speed up. You can see the table data in this [link](https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?race_id=1807732&dog_id=539402&r_date=2021-01-01&track_id=4&r_time=13%3A24&blocks=results-dog-header%2Cresults-dog-details).

This link gives you JSON and you can easily turn it into a list of data or dictionary.

see this :

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.get('http://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?race_id=1807732&dog_id=539402&r_date=2021-01-01&track_id=4&r_time=13%3A24&blocks=results-dog-header%2Cresults-dog-details')

dog_header = json.loads(data.content)['results-dog-header']
dog_details = json.loads(data.content)['results-dog-details']

print(dog_header)
print(dog_details)
```

Output:

```
{'dogs': [{'raceId': '1807732', 'position': '1', 'trap': '1', 'resultHandicap': '', 'name': 'Uknowyerwan', 'dogSex': '',....

{'forms': [{'rInstId': '1877705', 'raceTime': '2021-12-17 16:08', 'rFormDatetime': '2021-12-17 16:08', 'distMetre': '480', '....
```

These results are in the form of dictionary class.
You can convert them to different types using different methods.

Comment: you forgot to change 'results-dog-header' to 'results-dog-details' for dog_details

Comment: I fixed it and results ;)